# Bokeh - checkboxGroup plot: default plot only selected

Tags: python, python-2.7, bokeh

I used the following script to plot multilines using checkboxGroup.
My bokeh version is 0.12.7

The only problem I see is that it visualizes every line as default while only two boxes are checked off (from which I expect to see two line plots instead of all three).

Is there a way to show only those active ones (l0 and l2) as a default?

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis3
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import CheckboxGroup, CustomJS

output_file("line_on_off.html", title="line_on_off.py example")

p = figure()
props = dict(line_width=4, line_alpha=0.7)
x = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, 100)
l0 = p.line(x, np.sin(x), color=Viridis3[0], legend="Line 0", **props)
l1 = p.line(x, 4 * np.cos(x), color=Viridis3[1], legend="Line 1", **props)
l2 = p.line(x, np.tan(x), color=Viridis3[2], legend="Line 2", **props)

checkbox = CheckboxGroup(labels=["Line 0", "Line 1", "Line 2"],
                         active=[0, 2], width=100)
checkbox.callback = CustomJS.from_coffeescript(args=dict(l0=l0, l1=l1, l2=l2, checkbox=checkbox), code="""
l0.visible = 0 in checkbox.active;
l1.visible = 1 in checkbox.active;
l2.visible = 2 in checkbox.active;
""")

layout = row(checkbox, p)
show(layout)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `CustomJS` code runs *only when a checkbox is clicked*. So if you want some of the lines to not be visible by default, you will have to set that up yourself:

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis3
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import CheckboxGroup, CustomJS

output_file("line_on_off.html", title="line_on_off.py example")

p = figure()
props = dict(line_width=4, line_alpha=0.7)
x = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, 100)
l0 = p.line(x, np.sin(x), color=Viridis3[0], legend="Line 0", **props)
l1 = p.line(x, 4 * np.cos(x), color=Viridis3[1], legend="Line 1", **props)

l1.visible = False # NEW

l2 = p.line(x, np.tan(x), color=Viridis3[2], legend="Line 2", **props)

checkbox = CheckboxGroup(labels=["Line 0", "Line 1", "Line 2"],
                         active=[0, 2], width=100)
checkbox.callback = CustomJS.from_coffeescript(args=dict(l0=l0, l1=l1, l2=l2, checkbox=checkbox), code="""
l0.visible = 0 in checkbox.active;
l1.visible = 1 in checkbox.active;
l2.visible = 2 in checkbox.active;
""")

layout = row(checkbox, p)
show(layout)
```

However, please also not that none of this may be necessary. Bokeh has a built in interactive legend that can hide/show/mute different glyphs without any JS:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/legends.html#userguide-interaction-legends

Comment: That's a nice feature! I think I will try both and see which one would work better for my use case. Thank you!